# javascript CORS onerror handler

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cors, onerror

**Background**

- A few years ago there was an issue with the `onerror` handler and cross origin script tags, [more info on that](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/12/i-know-if-youre-logged-in-anywhere.html).
- Major browsers fixed the issue.
- Knowing this was a problem with detecting client side errors from CDNed scripts, they somewhat relaxed these constraints ([firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696301), [webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81438))

**Actual Question**

I'm hosting a simple page on localhost and including a script from a different domain (e.g. "sitea"), here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>window.onerror = function(e, f, g) { console.log('err',e,f,g) }</script>
</head>
<body><h2>test</h2>
<script src='http://siteA:8081/one.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script on `siteA` does this:

```
var foo; foo.bar;
```

Obviously that's going to throw since bar is undefined.

Unfortunately I'm still getiing the "Script Error" at line 0, like described in the tickets.

Note that I'm:

- Setting the crossdomain attribute.
- Seeing the "Origin" header on the request
- Setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to "*" and seeing it on the dev web tools.

I've tried it both in firefox and chrome, it doesn't work. Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Chrome actually [doesn't support cross-origin error reporting yet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159566).  Also, [more background on the issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14165776/201952).

Comment: Pablo, this should work in Firefox....  I assume you're using a recent version, right?  Support for this was added in Firefox 13.

Answer (score 3):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/vHmeb/) in Firefox 20 and Chrome [supports cross-origin error reporting as of version 30](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159566).

You can see that indeed the browsers do send an `Origin:` header because the `<script>` tag has a `crossorigin` attribute, and the error is properly reported because the server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.