# S3 CORS Headers not being sent for script tag in Chrome/Sarfari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-s3, cors

I am hosting JS assets on s3 and I am trying to get `window.onerror` information to correctly display by setting up CORS.

My script tag looks like this:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/application-c13462f856bbfc907cb077df58a54ff0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My s3 CORS rules look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

My understanding is that this should be sufficient. It is working great in Firefox, but both Chrome and Safari are not. What am I missing?

Below is a sample request. I am not seeing the appropriate headers being passed.

```
Request URL:https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/application-c13462f856bbfc907cb077df58a54ff0.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://app.p.com:3000/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31557600
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:224295
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Thu, 30 Jan 2014 19:37:01 GMT
ETag:"f6c6d4e784cc4eb0712a18db38abb97e"
Expires:Fri, 30 Jan 2015 01:47:35 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 29 Jan 2014 19:47:36 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:Q5dQulPTBoe/Xtr4oX3j5LEr6RTHsu2ILx7o6I2W7vmsXLe7eD6tE/0ed4F/XYns
x-amz-request-id:0B8E791D9D91E717
```

Specifically, I would have expected `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to show up in the response headers and `Origin: "http://app.p.com:3000"` to show up in the request headers.

The headers **are** correctly showing up and it is working fine in Firefox.

Comment: CORS is not needed for script tags - only for GET or POST requests made by XHR - this is probably why Chrome isn't sending the `Origin` header.

Comment: Thanks SilverlightFox. My understanding was that CORS is the only way to get scripts served from different origins to properly pass information to `window.onerror`. More info on what I am talking about here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696301 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159566

Comment: Here's [a post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17201082/413180) from June last year relating to the same issue with Chrome v28.

Comment: Yeah, that post is similar, but is most likely to have actually been a misconfigured server because they were seeing the error in FF too. It was also before the fix supposedly went into Chrome in September at v30. I am going to file an issue with crbug and will update if I get any new info.

Comment: Did you have any luck in finding out the cause?